# Produto é um namespace mas é usado como um tipo

Tags: c#, namespace

Tenho essa mensagem de erro:

> Produto é um namespace mas é usado como um tipo

Estava funcionando e quando cheguei para compilar, estou pegando esse erro. Como eu resolvo isso?

Comment: Se já funcionava, você deve ter colocado um caminho novo na seção de using na sua classe que possui uma pasta ou arquivo chamado Produto e isso faz com que o VS se perca em qual Produto usar e lança esse erro

Comment: OOOOU, você tem um namespace de mesmo nome da classe. exemplo        
namespace TimeTest
{
    class TimeTest
    {
}

Comment: Poste a sua classe e a implementação que a resposta virá em questão de minutos. Se você não puder mudar a estrutura poderá utilizar um alias para contornar a situação.

Comment: @pnet vc precisa postar a linha do erro em questão, contendo seu código.

Answer (score 3):

Voce possui um namespace em seu projeto chamado produto, assim como sua classe.

Provavelmente alguma pasta chamada produto que você adicionou. Modifique o nome da pasta para Produtos no plural e troque o namespace Produto  dos arquivos que estão dentro dessa pasta também para seu plural Produtos

Comment: Cfreio que o problema está no meu VS2017. Fiz um outro download do projeto, adicionei o que eu havia feito e funcionou. Não sei o que houve, mas está funcionando. Acho que zicou alguma coisa e não sei o que era e como já está funcionando, deixei pra lá. Fabri, foi o que eu havia pensado também. Procurei na solution e não consegui ver nada. Nessa tarefa eu apenas adicionei o namespace **Newtonsoft** e a **System.Net** e mais nada.